# Why I can't bind max size texture to framebuffer

Tags: c++, opengl

I use this code to bind the texture to a frame buffer, in my computer, now the w=h=32768

```c
    int w,h;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE, &w);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &h);
    w = h = std::min(w, h);
    
    unsigned int FBO;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
    unsigned int TBO;
    glGenTextures(1, &TBO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TBO);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, TBO, 0);
    unsigned int RBO;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &RBO);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, RBO);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, w, h);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, RBO);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        printf("%x\n", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
        std::cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
```

If I do so, glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) is return GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT

Then I make variable w=h=8192 (the variable also can't be 16384), the code can work well.

Is there some wrong with my code?

Update 1:

I find the max_value is 16384 if using my Integrated graphics, and it's 32768 in my Nvidia GPU.

But now I can't recur the result. I guess it's also linked with the state of my graphics, maybe my graphics don't have enough memory at that time?

Update 2:

Now I loop the same rendering process, the GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT is return again after several rendering.

Comment: Could you please also check `GL_MAX_FRAMEBUFFER_WIDTH` and `GL_MAX_FRAMEBUFFER_HEIGHT`?

Comment: These two values are both 32768 @BDL

Comment: See also [How to know max buffer storage size (using OpenGL) on a specific device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855353/how-to-know-max-buffer-storage-size-using-opengl-on-a-specific-device)

Comment: A 32768x32768 framebuffer with `RGBA8` color buffer and `DEPTH24_STENCIL8` depth buffer will consume **8GB** of memory. Are you sure the above code does not throw a `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` somewhere?